# Issue with pip - Traceback error - Messed up installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am having some issues running pip on my iTerm on my Mac (Big Sur 11.4)

I have already tried a couple things.
a. removed the Python framework from /Library/Frameworks (in an effort to clean remove python 3)
b. removed the Python apps from Applications

(that said, python3 still runs the interpreter)

Here is the error message, below.
Any input would be appreciated

Thank you

````
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application```
````

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have more than one soft links of pip in your default directory. Maybe try checking it by `where pip3` and rm the soft links of older versions.